# Connect two TV's via HDMI port

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, tv

I been searching around if I can actually connect two displays's via their HDMI port?
The source will be a VGA from a PC.

- Will it be distribute the screen across two displays's since the two displays's are connected via HDMI port?
- Or nothing will happens?
- Or it will damage the two displays's?

I am thinking about the screen will be cascaded, like my screen will be wider?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just cause a socket fits, dosen't mean its a good idea.

HDMI isn't designed to daisy chain as far as I know. Displayport *is*, but that requires the devices being used to passthrough the data to have a "special" displayport out connector, and be connected to displayport at the PC.

At best, nothing will happen. At worst, you may damage the TVs or ports. It *certainly* will not work that way.

There's *certainly* nothing in the average TV or display that would take a VGA signal, upscale it or otherwise convert the signal into digital data for 2 screens.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to daisy chain the tvs which is what your question sounds like, then I am not aware of any domestic tvs that can do that. there are some custom systems for commercial application, like in big stage displays, but more often they come from a main controller, splitting the signal out.

if you want to extend your pc desktop across 2 tvs - then any decent graphics card with dual HDMI output could do that, and you could send the "VGA" signal to your monitor, even if you had to use a some kind of DVI adapter on the card to your VGA monitor.

or you can get splitter boxes that will take your VGA output and then send it to multiple HDMI - but to get an extending function rather than just mirrored would likely be expensive.